# Unable to delete laravel project

Tags: php, apache, laravel, centos

When I try to delete laravel project. The following files still remain in the folder.

1. **doctrine dbal**
2. **php-parse**
3. **php unit**
4. **psysh**

I am using **Apache/2.4.26** and **PHP** version: **7.0.13** on centos 6

I have attached the screen shot of the files below.

[image: laravel project la1 screenshot]

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebooting your server? (Depending on your localhost software this could help)

Comment: Yes I did that but still I am not able to delete the file